# PHP can't write to /tmp folder anymore after Apache update

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, file-permissions, ubuntu-18.04, tmp

Linux dist: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Server version: Apache/2.4.29
PHP Version: 7.4.20 with PHP-FPM

Recently this server did an automatic upgrade of Apache and ever since PHP can't write to /tmp breaking many sites. PHP functions like tmpfile() and move_uploaded_file() are returning false. PHP's file_put_contents() and fopen() when attempting to write to that folder also fail. sys_get_temp_dir() returns /tmp

The permission on /tmp is drwxrwxrwt which I understand is correct. I tried df -h and the disk is not anywhere close to running out of space or anything like that. The open_basedir setting in php.ini is blank which is also correct.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Where did you get PHP from?

Comment: Anything/anyone can write to `/tmp`. So, IMO your PHP code is likely not trying to write to `/tmp` but somewhere else. Check `upload_tmp_dir` in php.ini? see - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16091596/503621

Comment: My temporary solution to this was to just restart the process php-fpm until Apache eventually fixed the problem in a subsequent update. This was resolved a while ago. I am just posting about it now.

Answer (score 1):

Has the PHP-FPM service been "updated" to use the PrivateTmp setting?

If it *has*, then even though you *ask* for /tmp, PHP will not *give* you /tmp!
See [php-fpm temporary file path problem](https://www.programmersought.com/article/99923565044/).

Comment: Thanks! I've been scratching my head over this for hours. Whilst setting `upload_tmp_dir` fixes the problem, your answer explains the source of the issue. Much appreciated.